# How do I create a "dummy" module object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a function that takes a module object as an argument and does something to it -- maybe monkeypatches it. For testing purposes, how do I create a dummy module object to pass to it?

Comment: It's just a regular object, you don't need to do anything special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.ModuleType))

```
>>> import types
>>> types.ModuleType('my_module')
<module 'my_module'>
```